# URL for Created Services View?

Tags: 7, views, services

Apologies for the newb question, but: Is there a way to see the entire URL of a Services View I've created? I know it lets me name the path, however when I navigate to the URL, I get "View not found" (though the Views preview shows perfectly). I keep thinking maybe I'm just typing it in wrong? Right now, I'm navigating to:

http://domainnamehere.com/endpointname/views/viewname

Thanks all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the right url will like domain/endpoint/services_url If you need to get any view the url will be like

[domain/endpoint/viewname?display_id=block_id](http://www.domain.com/endpoint/viewname?display_id=block_id)

More details found [here](https://www.drupal.org/project/services_views)